# Viewing a webpage on a laptop via wifi hotspot

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, web

I have a laptop, on which is an application that *does stuff*. The *stuff* that this laptop does includes changing values stored in a WAMP local database.

What I want to be able to do, is connect to this laptop (from a mobile /tablet), and view a PHP page on it. My idea would be to use a wifi dongle to turn the laptop into a wireless access point.

However, if I did manage this, would it even be possible to then view the web page on the laptop?

If not, do I have any other way of viewing a page on this laptop wirelessly?

Normally I would get the laptop to update a web enabled database, and then view that via the internet on any other device, however the client has pointed out that they don't want the data in the database to be on an internet-connected device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad-Hoc network using a dongle would be one way to go.  Otherwise, you could get a wireless router, but don't connect the router to the internet.

Yes, if you are serving the page out to another device, you can still view the page on the laptop that's serving it.

### Step 1: Enabling Internet Sharing on the Host Computer

To enable Internet sharing on the host computer, do the following:

1.From the Windows XP desktop, click **Start**, click **Control Panel**, click **Network and Internet Connections**, and then click **Network Connections**.

2.Right-click the Ethernet network connection that is used to access the Internet, and then click **Properties**.

3.On the **Advanced** tab, select the **Allow other network users to connect through this computer’s Internet connection** check box and clear the **Allow other network users to control or disable this shared Internet connection** check box.

4.Click **OK** to save changes to your connection.

5.You might be prompted with a **Local Network** message box that explains how your computer’s configuration is being changed. Click **Yes** to enable Internet sharing.

### Step 2: Creating an Ad Hoc Wireless Network on the Host Computer

To create an ad hoc wireless network to share Internet access with the other WLAN computers on a computer running Windows XP, do the following:

1. From the Windows XP desktop, click **Start**, click **Control Panel**, click **Network and Internet Connections**, and then click **Network Connections**.
2. Right-click the wireless network connection, and then click **Properties**.
3. Click the **Wireless Networks** tab.
4. In the wireless network adapter properties dialog box, click **Add** under **Preferred networks**.
5. On the **Association** tab, type the name of your ad hoc wireless network in **Network name (SSID)**. For example, you could name your wireless network **AdHocInternet**.
6. Select the **This is a computer-to-computer (ad hoc) network** check box and clear the **The key is provided for me automatically** check box.
7. In **Network Authentication**, select **Open**.
8. In **Data encryption**, select **WEP**.
9. In **Network key**, type the WEP key. The WEP key should be a random sequence of hexadecimal digits or numbers, letters, and punctuation.
10. In **Confirm network key**, retype the WEP key.
11. Click **OK** to save changes to the wireless network.
12. Click **OK** to save changes to the wireless network adapter.

These instructions configure an encryption key for wireless communications on the ad hoc wireless network. You must tell the other users who want to access the Internet the WEP key. You can create an ad hoc wireless network without requiring encryption and an encryption key, but it is not recommended.

### Step 3. Connect other Computers to your new Ad Hoc Wireless Network

To connect each other laptop computer to the newly created ad hoc mode wireless network, do the following:

1. Once the new ad hoc wireless network is created, Windows XP on other laptop computers should detect it and prompt you with a **One or more wireless networks are available** or **Wireless networks detected** message in the notification area of your taskbar.
2. Click the notification message.

   If you are not notified, right-click the wireless network adapter in Network Connections and click **View Available Wireless Networks**.

   You should see the **Wireless Network Connection** dialog box (for Windows XP with SP2), a dialog box with the name of the wireless connection (for Windows XP with SP1), or the **Connect to Wireless Network** dialog box (for Windows XP with no service packs installed). An example of the **Wireless Network Connection** dialog box for Windows XP with SP2 is shown in the following figure.
3. For Windows XP with SP2, click the name of the new ad hoc wireless network in the list, and then click **Connect**. When prompted by the **Wireless Network Connection** dialog box, the WEP key in **Network key** and **Confirm network key**, and then click **Connect**.

For Windows XP with SP1, click the name of the new ad hoc wireless network in **Available networks**, type the WEP key in **Network key** and **Confirm network key**, and then click **Connect**.

For Windows XP with no service packs installed, click the name of the new ad hoc wireless network in **Available networks**, type the WEP key in **Network key**, and then click **Connect**.

Now that the laptop computer is connected to the ad hoc wireless network, you must configure it for either Windows Firewall or ICF and automatic addressing by doing the following:

1. From the Windows XP desktop, click **Start**, click **Control Panel**, click **Network and Internet Connections**, and then click **Network Connections**.
2. Right-click the network connection that corresponds to the wireless network adapter, and then click **Properties**.
3. For computers running Windows XP with SP2, click the **Advanced** tab, and then click **Settings**. From the **Windows Firewall** dialog box, click **On**, and then click **OK**.

For computers running Windows XP with SP1 or Windows XP with no service packs installed, click the **Advanced** tab, and then select the **Protect my computer and network by limiting or preventing access to this computer from the Internet** check box.

4. Click the **General** tab, double-click **Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)** in the **This connection uses the following items** list.
5. On the **General** tab, click **Obtain an IP address automatically** and **Obtain DNS server address automatically**.
6. Click **OK** to save the changes to the configuration of Internet Protocol (TCP/IP).
7. Click **OK** to save the changes to your connection’s configuration.

[Source](http://www.labnol.org/software/ad-hoc-wireless-network-in-windows-xp/11486/)

Comment: Thanks, glad to hear it's possible. Where can I find a good guide to turning a wifi dongle into a hotspot and also how to then view a file that is on that device? Thanks

Comment: What's the OS and the make/model of the Dongle?  The instructions are generally specific to this information.

Comment: OS is windows XP (unfortunately) and the dongle is a 3COM OfficeConnect Wireless 54mbps 11g USB Adapter

Comment: @Wayneio Check the steps above.

Comment: @Wayneio Did this work for you?